# using automator to select random lines of text and then paste into browser

Tags: macos, shell, automator

I've got a test file with a bunch of words in it named **input.txt**.

In `automator`, I'm using run shell script to execute
`sort -Ru input.txt | head -3`, this returns 3 of the values from the list.

What I want to do next would be take that output and copy it then paste as plain text into a browser.

I've been looking around and I see a couple steps forward but maybe not in the right direction

```
A)
[set value of variable] -
 use this to save previous items into a variable
[ask for confirmation] -
 prints these onto a pop up
```

or

```
B)
[new textedit document] -
 just save a new file with whatever has been copied
```

However I'm not sure how to move forward from there.

Again my goal is to take the outputs from the initial shell script and get them copied to the clipboard, so they can be pasted into a browser at a specific location.

AFTER pasting into the browser ideally I would use some sort of mouse recording to press a couple buttons on different parts of the screen.

If you are interested in the specifics I'm using this website https://www.prosepainter.com and want to essentially randomly select text to paste into it and then automate some iterations while saving the between iterations.

`shell/automator` are pretty new to me, so I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

thanks!

Comment: There is a `Copy to Clipboard` action.

Comment: thank you @red_menace that was super helpful!
I got that added and then tried to use the built in even recorded via the red record button with mostly positive results. The last button press to save the picture doesn't seem to be taking but if nothing else this saves a lot of repetitive steps as is.